# Stream OWT app not streaming after IOS update to 14.7.1

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, rtcp

I have video stream app based on OWT framework / Swift. It works fine (IOS 14.4 - 14.6 for sure) but after update IOS to 14.7.1 I have many strange messages in debug console and app stop sending stream to server. I dont know if messages connect with problem with streaming but on other devices (ihpone 7, XS etc) with IOS 14.4 or 14.6 there are no such messages and streaming works fine. On new device (iphone 12 mini with IOS 14.7.1) I could only receive stream but not publish. And there are no any other messages in debug. I think problem somewere in new IOS network/security setting maybe.. but where?

Here are messages in console (they not directly connect with streaming but..):

2021-08-09 14:06:49.719005+0300 iew[661:70198] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C1 xx.xx.xx.xx:8081 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-09 14:06:49.719780+0300 iew[661:70198] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C1 xx.xx.xx.xx:8081 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
021-08-09 14:15:36.111907+0300 iew[661:77943] [tcp] tcp_input [C17:2] flags=[R] seq=4168261029, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSE_WAIT rcv_nxt=4168261029, snd_una=4000330730
2021-08-09 14:15:36.112297+0300 iew[661:77943] Connection 17: received failure notification
2021-08-09 14:15:36.346537+0300 iew[661:78328] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C25.1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-09 14:15:36.346633+0300 iew[661:78328] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C25.1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-09 14:15:36.750861+0300 iew[661:78110] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C26.1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-09 14:15:36.751236+0300 iew[661:78110] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C26.1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-08-09 14:15:52.059984+0300 iew[661:78340] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C27 xx.xx.xx.xx:8081 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-08-09 14:15:52.060394+0300 iew[661:78340] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C27 xx.xx.xx.xx:8081 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed

Comment: Are you by any chance using a Firebase module in your project?

Comment: no I dont use Firebase

Comment: I am having similar issues. Any news on that?